# Should I use 'able' or 'able to' in this question, even if it means that the sentence ends with 'to'?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

My doubt is: Which of these two sentences is correct?

> We are always looking for ways to reach all the learners in our classroom as effectively as we are able.

OR:

> We are always looking for ways to reach all the learners in our classroom as effectively as we are able to.

Note that the second one ends with *to*.

Comment: You may be interested in our sister site for English language learners: http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: No, your **question** is *which of these two sentences is correct?* Your doubt is  whether or not you correctly  understand the concept you are asking about, which is why you are asking your question here. You are not asking your doubt.

Comment: Did you not six hours earlier ask the same question on this site: [Using (or not) the word "to" at the end of a question with "be able"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/321718/using-or-not-the-word-to-at-the-end-of-a-question-with-be-able)?

Comment: @AlanCarmack Could you be a little more condescending?  I'm not sure you your message is getting across to a low-rep poster.

Answer (score 0):

Just end with "as effectively as we can", which is excellent English and sidesteps your problem.